# Calling Angularjs function from jquery does not allow change variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, angularjs, html

I have a variable under my scope and when I try to reset it in a function it is throwing me an exception.
Please if some one know something about this, share the solution.

[You can find the full code in this jsFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/1u3netsj/)
If you delete line 173 the code will works.

Controller variable declaration:

```
angular.module('timeSheetApp', []).controller('TimeSheetController', function ($scope, $http) {
$scope.TimeSheet = {
        Tables: [{
            Projects:{
                Project: ":)",
                Activities: [{
                    Activity:"",
                    Sun: 0.00,
                    Mon: 0.00,
                    Tue: 0.00,
                    Wen: 0.00,
                    Thu: 0.00,
                    Fri: 0.00,
                    Sat: 0.00,
                    Total: 0.00
                }],
                DefaultProjectText: "Select a Project",
                IsDisabled: true,
                ProjectNumber: 0,
                Day: {}
            }
        }],
};
});
```

`

When I call this function inside my controller sends an exception:

```
 $scope.SetDays = function () {

    $scope.TimeSheet.Tables = [{
            Projects: {
                Project: ":)",
                Activities: [{
                    Activity: "",
                    Sun: 0.00,
                    Mon: 0.00,
                    Tue: 0.00,
                    Wen: 0.00,
                    Thu: 0.00,
                    Fri: 0.00,
                    Sat: 0.00,
                    Total: 0.00
                }],
                DefaultProjectText: "Select a Project",
                IsDisabled: true,
                ProjectNumber: 0,
                Day: {}
            }
        }]
```

`}`

This is the jquery Call:

```
   <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function () {
                var startDate;
                var endDate;

                localStorage.clear();
                //localStorage.removeItem('endDate');

                $('#containerId').css('margin-left', '5%');
                $('#containerId').css('margin-right', '5%');
                $('#containerId').css('width', '100%');

                var selectCurrentWeek = function () {
                    window.setTimeout(function () {
                        $('.week-picker').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day a').addClass('ui-state-active')
                    }, 1);
                }


                $('.week-picker').datepicker({
                    showOtherMonths: true,
                    selectOtherMonths: true,
                    onSelect: function (dateText, inst) {
                        var date = $(this).datepicker('getDate');
                        startDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay());
                        endDate = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
                        var dateFormat = inst.settings.dateFormat || $.datepicker._defaults.dateFormat;
                        $('#startDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, startDate, inst.settings));
                        $('#endDate').text($.datepicker.formatDate(dateFormat, endDate, inst.settings));

                        var daysInMonth = new Date(date.getFullYear(), date.getMonth(), 0).getDate();
                        localStorage.setItem('daysInMonth', daysInMonth);
                        localStorage.setItem('endDate', date.getDate() - date.getDay() + 6);
                        selectCurrentWeek();
                        angular.element('#TimeSheetController').scope().SetDays();
                        angular.element('#TimeSheetController').scope().$apply();
                    },
                    beforeShowDay: function (date) {
                        var cssClass = '';
                        if (date >= startDate && date <= endDate)
                            cssClass = 'ui-datepicker-current-day';
                        return [true, cssClass];
                    },
                    onChangeMonthYear: function (year, month, inst) {
                        selectCurrentWeek();
                    }
                });
                $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').find('.ui-datepicker-current-day').click();

                $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mousemove', function () { $(this).find('td a').addClass('ui-state-hover'); });
                $('.week-picker .ui-datepicker-calendar tr').live('mouseleave', function () { $(this).find('td a').removeClass('ui-state-hover'); });
            });
            </script>
```

Comment: what is your question?

Comment: How can I do to when I call  function SetDays the application does not crashes, this is the error: 0x800a139e - JavaScript runtime error: [$rootScope:infdig] errors.angularjs.org/1.3.14/$rootScope/…

Comment: I need to reset the array "TimeSheet" every time that I select a diferent week in the calendar

Comment: Is in the fiddle 173 or 172 I think, in html file under controller script